# How can I rotate text in Paint.NET?

Tags: windows-xp, paint.net

How can I rotate text in Paint.NET?

OS is Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the `dpy plugins`.  There are tools in there for rotating, spiraling, and doing other such things to text.  Here is the link:

http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/16643-dpys-pack/

Comment: Thanks, you both get +1, but the accept has to go to @typoknig. fnnuy.

Comment: @Xavierjazz - it's actually the same plugin I linked to - but never mind ;)

Answer (score 8):

You could write the text to a separate layer and then rotate that layer (**Layers > Rotate/Zoom**), though it might be difficult to get the exact rotation you want.

A more direct approach is to select the text with the selection tools, choose the Move Selected Pixels tool and then right-click and drag to rotate.

There is also an [extension](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/16643-dpys-pack/) which is part of the "dpy plugins" pack, that adds an option to create text at an angle. Disclaimer - I haven't used this.